# SASS Variables converting to Hex Codes

Tags: css, sass, osx-mountain-lion, compass-sass, codekit

I have been using SASS for a month, love it.

However, when I create a variable such as:

```
$darkgrey:rgb(82,81,83);
```

Then decide re-use the variables, say in a specific p tag? In the body:

```
body{
    p.ahh-whatever{
        color:$darkgrey;
    }
}
```

However it always seems to come up as a HEX in all browsers. Is there a reason for this? Do I need to use RGBA with 1 Opacity...

Software Being Used:

I also use Foundation 3 inline with Compass-Style. In addition to CodeKit to compile my code, and Sublime Text 2 for my editor. Operating System is OSX 10.8 (New IMac 27").

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SASS will output hex whenever possible, because almost all browsers will understand it.
(Not all browsers will "get" RGB values or RGBA values.)

if you do specify a an rgba value, SASS will output it as such

for instance :

```
rgba(blue, 0.2)
```

will output :

```
rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)
```

see : [Sass RGBA instances documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/Sass/Script/Functions.html#rgba-instance_method)

Comment: sweet, thanks for answering. I thought it may have been a quirk in Compass or something..

+1